# How to run array operations when elements in a pandas series are lists

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, series

In a course I'm taking the instructor ran the following code in Jupyter Notebook-

```
ww2_cas = Series([8700000, 4300000, 3000000, 2100000, 400000], index = ['USSR', 'Germany', 'China', 'Japan', 'USA'])
ww2_cas[ww2_cas > 4000000]
```

The program returned a pandas series with the countries whose casualties were above 4000000

I tried experimenting with this by creating the following series and doing an array operation on it but I got an error

```
marks = Series([[33,67,70,73],[90,82,43,76],[56,79,82,55]], index=["John", "Kiara", "Charles"])
marks[(sum(marks)/4) >= 70]
```

The error is:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Is there a way to do this in 1 line as in the instructor's example or do I have to create another Series to house the True/False values of the indices

Answer (score 0):

Try via `apply()`:

```
out=marks[marks.apply(sum)/4>=70]
```

**OR**

```
out=marks[marks.apply(lambda x:(sum(x)/4) >= 70)]
```

**Explaination:**

this code `marks[(sum(marks)/4) >= 70]` doesn't work because the values inside marks are of type `list`

Comment: I tried it and it works. Thanks a ton for helping out!

Comment: @JaiGaurav If it helped you then try considering accepting this answer...please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)......Thnx **:)**